# WinRT SQLite Encryption

Tags: database, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store

I'm building a Windows Store application that uses SQLite for data storage. I have found out, that the database is easily accessible through User's local folder (actually all apps have all data publicly exposed). Is there a way to at least weakly protect the database from access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to look at ProtectedData class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider.aspx

It exposes easy to use Protect / Unprotect methods that can be used to encrypt / decrypt that at app level. Encrypt data before writing to db and unencrypt before consuming

Comment: Good answer, any ideas of the performance hit from the encryption/decryption process?

Comment: there is always a performance hit.. however this is simpler form of encryption and shouldn't be as expensive as PKI.. you only encrypt sensitive data and not blanket encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I also looking for the same solution and found sqlite-crypt at http://sqlite-crypt.com/download.htm

I don't know whether this one good enough or not. There is a trial version that limit passphrase to 6 characters and store it as plain text in the header. It won't be suitable if you want complete data protection. But for testing, maybe it's worth a try. I don't have a chance to  test it yet since I still working on the server side of my project. I'll update it when I've test it in the future.

EDIT: Ok. I've test the trial version and it's worked well with modificated version of SqliteWinRT wrapper on codeplex. Note that the trial is limited to 5-6 characters of passphrase and this phasephrase is stored in plain text, plus it's in x86 compiled binary, which means it won't work for actual product which need ARM support. You have to purchase the binary to get the production-ready binaries.